# erb - How to substitute a string (gsub) which contains legit backslashes?

Tags: puppet, erb, hiera, eruby

I had the following problem with erb in combination with Puppet, Hiera and templates:

Via Hiera I got the following strings as variables:

First the variable `example` in an array (data[example])

```
something with _VARIABLE_ in it
```

and variable `example_information` with

```
some kind of \1 and maybe also a \2
```

Now I wanted to substitute `_VARIABLE_` in a Puppet template with the second string which contains a legit backslash () in it. So I did it like this:

```
result=data['example'].gsub('_VARIABLE_', @example_information)
```

So I took `example` out of an array and filled the placeholder with `@example_information`.

The result was as follows:

```
something with some kind of  and maybe also a  in it
```

There was no backslash as `gsub` interpreted them as backreferences. So how can I solve my issue to preserve my backslashes without double escape them in the Hiera file? I need the Hiera variable further in the code without double escaped backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

I now made this to solve that specific problem as follows:

Variable again `example`

```
something with _VARIABLE_ in it
```

and variable `example_information` with

```
some kind of \1 and maybe also a \2
```

Code part in the template:

```
# we need to parse out any backslashes
info_temp=example_information.gsub('\\', '__BACKSLASH__')

# now we substitute the variables with real data (but w/o backslashes)
result_temp=data['example'].gsub(/__ITEM_NAME__/, info_temp)

# now we put together the real string with backslashes again as before
result=result_temp.gsub('__BACKSLASH__', '\\')
```

Now the result looks as follows:

```
something with some kind of \1 and maybe also a \2 in it
```

### Note

Maybe there is a better way to do it but on my research I didn't stumble upon a better solution so please add comments if you know a better way to do it.